# Default account in Twitter app

Tags: accounts, twitter

I have two Twitter accounts in my Twitter app, one personal and one for work. I added the personal one first, and it appears first in the Android Accounts settings. I want the Twitter app to use the personal account when it first opens, but it always defaults to the other one - can I change this?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest logging out of both and signing into your personal account first. Then the work account. This should then default to the first account you signed up with...

-edit (sorry for being so stupid)-
Try another twitter client such as [twiddle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handlerexploit.tweedle&referrer=utm_source?androidcentral?tm_medium?blog?tm_campaign?bloglink) (free) or [talon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klinker.android.twitter&referrer=utm_source?androidcentral?tm_medium?blog?tm_campaign?bloglink) (Paid). These may have the feature your looking for...

I can't comment as I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: He stated clearly in the original post:  "I added the personal one first"

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that on both my current and previous phones, adding the accounts both ways round. It might be alphabetical or something.

Comment: Updated answer to make it a bit better